# Spring boot creates List out of multiple boolean fields

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to store a class named `Project` with the following attributes:

```
@Entity
public class Project implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // Some more attributes...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectServices_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ProjectServices projectServices;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "projectCategories_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ProjectCategories projectCategories;

    // Constructors

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

The `projectCategories` and `projectServices` look very similar, because they both only store lots of boolean variables.

They do look something like this:

```
@Entity
public class ProjectCategories implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "projectCategories", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Project project;

    private boolean category0;
    // Categories 1 - 244
    private boolean category245;

    // Constructors

    // Getters and Setters

    @JsonIgnore
    @IgnoreForBinding
    public List<Boolean> getBooleanData() {
        List<Boolean> data = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                if (field.getType() == boolean.class) {
                    data.add((Boolean) field.get(this));
                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }

        }
        return data;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @IgnoreForBinding
    public void setBooleanData(List<Boolean> data) {
        Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            try {
                if (field.getType() == boolean.class && !data.isEmpty()) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    boolean a = data.get(0);
                    //Boolean a = Boolean.valueOf();
                    field.setBoolean(this, a);
                    data.remove(0);
                } else if (field.getType() == boolean.class) {
                    field.setBoolean(this, false);
                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Problem:** When I want to send a `Project` to the frontend it creates a JSON Object with a List of booleans for the type `ProjectServices` and a Object for the type `ProjectCategories`. **I want both of them to be a List of booleans.**

The two classes `ProjectServices` and `ProjectCategories` are basically the same and one could argue to simply use the one which is converted to a List of booleans, but the structure of both of the classes will change in the future. Therefore simply using one class is not the desired solution.

Thank you for your help!

Cheers, nicklas

Comment: Create a DTO, load with your data from the entities and return the DTO as response.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am setting up a DTO just now and having some trouble with the ```modelMapper```. Because I use some ```Set<>```'s which are not compatible with PersistentSet.
Error message: ```1) Converter org.modelmapper.internal.converter.MergingCollectionConverter@93744a4 failed to convert org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet to java.util.Set.```. Do I need to modify the setter of the DTO and if yes how? :D

Comment: If you have not work much with  DTO and ModelMapper, I would recommend writing your own mapper class, `ProjectMapper.toDTO()` (you can inject the mapper). After you have running code, you can always refactor with "better" libs.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I actually solved my problem with DTOs, but the even easier way is to define a new getter and use @JsonIgnore on the others. I know this is not the perfect solution but its an easy workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, @PeterMmm was right. Using DTOs did solve the problem and is the correct way to do it.

Another workaround was using an additional getter which returns the List and use `@JsonIgnore` on the actual getter.